# What is the best way to put some data in an std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have a function that needs data in a std::vector but I have them as different data. so I have this code:

```
void UseData(int x, int y, int z)
{
     std::vector<int> data;
     data.pushback(x);
     data.pushback(y);
     data.pushback(z);
     processData(data);
 }
```

Is there any better way to put the data inside the std::vector?

Comment: IMO it would be a little better to reserve space in your vector before pushing any data. That way you won't have to reallocate memory each time your vector gets an element added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With C++11, you can use an `std::initializer_list`:

```
void UseData(int x, int y, int z) {
    std::vector<int> data {x,y,z};
    process(data);
}
```